# Passing JQuery Arrays to Nested Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm having problems with dynamically adding a row to a table using data stored in two arrays (**categories** and **treatments**). The arrays are fine, I've determined that.

When passing just the categories array the new row displays but the select box reads [object:object], it's clearly blank.

When I pass a second array with it, as shown below, the console reads 'undefined is not a function'.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```
 // Add an extra row when button is clicked
 var counter = 1;
   $('input.add').click(categories, treatments, function(){
      counter++;      

      var newRow = '<tr><td><label for="category' + counter + '">Category</label></td><td><select id="category' + counter + '" name="category' + counter + '" required="required">';      

      $.each(categories, function(key, value) {   
      $('#category' + counter)
         newRow += '<option value ="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
      });

      newRow += '</select></td><td><label for="treatment' + counter + '">Treatment</label></td><td><select id="treatment' + counter + '" name="treatment' + counter + '">';

      $.each(treatments, function(key, value) {   
      $('#treatment' + counter)
         newRow += '<option value ="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
      });    

      newRow += '</select></td></tr>';     

      $('table.treatments').append(newRow);
   });
});
```

Comment: Please create a JsFiddle with the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter for the jQuery `.click()` is an Object, and you're trying to pass two arrays.

This should work for you (remember to check for the missing semi-colons):

```
// Create an Object obj containing the two arrays.
$('input.add').click(obj = { categories: categories, treatments: treatments }, function () {
    counter++;

    var newRow = '<tr><td><label for="category' + counter + '">Category</label></td><td><select id="category' + counter + '" name="category' + counter + '" required="required">';

    // Use the obj.
    $.each(obj.categories, function (key, value) {
        $('#category' + counter);
        newRow += '<option value ="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
    });

    newRow += '</select></td><td><label for="treatment' + counter + '">Treatment</label></td><td><select id="treatment' + counter + '" name="treatment' + counter + '">';

    // Use the obj.
    $.each(obj.treatments, function (key, value) {
        $('#treatment' + counter);
        newRow += '<option value ="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
    });

    newRow += '</select></td></tr>';

    $('table.treatments').append(newRow);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/nexxppef/1/)

[jQuery .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, that makes sense to me. The JFiddle you put up works perfectly, bizarrely though when copying and pasting the code I still have the same problem, the input box is showing [Object, object]. I have added a console log line to the function and it displays perfectly on the console, I can't understand why its not working properly

Comment: SOLVED - it was due to the structure of the arrays I believe as changing value to value.category did the trick. Thanks for your help, very much appreciated!